# Join document by field that is not a primary key

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have an external system that creates documents (orders) on my platform. The reference to my platform is maintained through a string code, which is not a primary key. So, I have the following entities:

```
{
    docType: "submission",
    code: "XPTO28",
    name: "test-sub"
}

{
    docType: "order",
    code: "XPTO28",
    value: "100$"
}
```

Is there any query to associate order documents to submission documents without using primary keys, or must I do so programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it programatically. Joins in N1QL are currently limited to linking a field (or something that can be reconstructed from a field, eg. concatenating a prefix) to the primary key of the joined keyspace.